# Jquery TokenInput not loading results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I have:

```
$('.titulares').tokenInput("http://localhost/ajax/ajax.php",{
            tokenLimit: 1,
            queryParam: 'query',
            propertyToSearch: 'nome',
            resultsLimit: 2,
            tokenValue: 'id',
            noResultsText: 'Nada',
            searchingText: "Procurando...",
            hintText: "Buscar titular",
            method: 'GET',
            onResult(){
                alert('a');
            }           
        });
```

ajax.php JSON output:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":12,
      "nome":"Joe Bill"
   },
   {  
      "id":13,
      "nome":"PJ"
   },
   {  
      "id":14,
      "nome":"John"
   },
   {  
      "id":16,
      "nome":"Acme"
   },
   {  
      "id":17,
      "nome":"Acme2"
   },
   {  
      "id":18,
      "nome":"Acme3"
   }
]
```

The code shows loading texts, but the JSON output is not renderized in text field and onResult is not fired

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code not work because you write wrong syntax. if you fix it, your code will run normally now.

```
onResult: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/yimiwumije/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I test this code, but it not returns the results correctly... For example, i try "Acme" and the results not appears...

Comment: 1. why results is not correctly, because i dont use my real server. so what ever do you write, it will ALWAYS return same result. im using json hosting for this demo. you can see the url to notice that result always same all the time. this will not happen if i use my own php script which i dont want to show you, because our topic is about the tokeninput (javascript) not the server script.

Comment: 2. why we cant see Acme? this is because you specify this parameter `resultsLimit: 2` which means trim all result except  the TOP 2. and because my json is static (always same like that), we only see `joe bill` and `PJ` as the only result. because both of them is number 1 and 2 in our json